# why class selector property is not getting high precedence over type precedence?

Tags: css, css-specificity

I am trying  to understand specificity in the css. I have used class selector `.grandparent` and type selector `p` for changing the color of all the paragraph inside each`.grandparent`.

What I understand is that class is more specific than type, and hence I was expecting the color of each paragraph inside `.grandparent` to be salmon. As color is inheritable and p is the child of `.grandparent` so all color of each paragraph is expected to be `salmon`.However, this is not happening. Please help me to understand this.

**HTML:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Inside Body</p>
    <div class="grandparent">
        <p>Inside Grand Parent Div</p>
        <div class="parent">
            <p>Inside Parent Div</p>
            <div class="child">
                <p>Inside Child Div</p>
                <button class="warning">
                    what color background?
                  </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
p{
    color: green;
}
.grandparent{
    color: salmon;
    
}
```

Comment: `As color is inheritable and p is the child of .grandparent` --> inheritance enters in play only if you don't define any color which not the case here

Comment: I have one question though.How would I get salmon color from grandparent

Comment: One another question : if I use CSS `div{ color: green;} .grandparent{ color: red;}`. 
I can see the .grandparent css is applied in grandparent div, due to which pargraph directly inside this div is red color.The div type css rule is applied to the .parent and .child due to which pargraph directly inside these divs is in red color. My question is why .grandparent css rule applied to the granparent div as the css rule is already defined for every div. I guess, it is due to specificity. If it is then how browser decides when to invoke specifity and when to not.